# Error occure:Interceptor does not exist in magento2

Tags: magento2.3

[image: my controller file is]I have created custom module but I am getting following error how I could solve it :

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magik\Productslider\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magik\Productslider\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magik\Productsli...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php:49]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magik\Productsli...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magik\Productsli...', array()) called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magik\Productsli...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\ActionFactory.php:44]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Magik\Productsli...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Router\Base.php:306]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#, array('moduleFrontName' => 'productslider', 'actionPath' => NULL, 'actionName' => NULL)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Router\Base.php:167]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php:95]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#) called at [vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#11 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000001f6d7f000000000077ac7030#, &Closure#000000001f6d7f3d0000000077ac7030#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:135]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#) called at [vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#13 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000001f6d7f000000000077ac7030#, &Closure#000000001f6d7f3d0000000077ac7030#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:135]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#), NULL) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php:26]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001f6d7eff0000000077ac7030#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:137]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:24]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:261]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000001f6d7e810000000077ac7030#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Comment: Remove the generated folder and then check again.

Comment: Remove Semicolon after $resultPageFactory and after run setup upgrade

Comment: which folder I have to remove

Answer (score 1):

**Please Follow these steps:**

> 1. rm -rf generated/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]
> 2. bin/magento se:di:co

**This generates the interceptor files for your module.**

Comment: Not working again it gives same error

Comment: I am using magento2.3 on windows...Everytime whenever I am trying to use factory class it gives me Interceptor does not exist error

Comment: Then there might be a file name issue

Comment: check you might not have added that in above use section

Answer (score 0):

use Magik\Productslider\Model\ResultPageFactory;

and then run command php bin/magento setup:di:compile